# Oracle 19c Inserting data from JSON into a table in PL/SQL

Tags: json, xml, oracle, plsql

I have some existing working PL/SQL code running in a 19c Oracle database that uses the `dbms_xmlstore.insertxml(...)` to insert data into a table.  For this to work the XML is structured so that the element names match the table column names, so the XML looks something like this:

```
<ROWSET>
  <ROW>
    <EMPLOYEE_ID>920</EMPLOYEE_ID>
    <SALARY>1800</SALARY>
  </ROW>
  <ROW>
    <EMPLOYEE_ID>921</EMPLOYEE_ID>
    <SALARY>2000</SALARY>
  </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

I now need to do something similar but with JSON data so is there an something equivalent that allows me to insert rows into a table directly from the JSON object or to to convert the JSON to XML and carry on with the present working code?

EDIT:
The key part that I need to replicate is the way the insertxml() function takes the column names from the XML without me needing to supply them to the function.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the `JSON_TABLE` command as part of an `INSERT` statement.  Like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO employees
SELECT *
FROM JSON_TABLE('{employees:[
                   {employee_id: 123, salary: 100000}, 
                   {employee_id: 234, salary: 90000}
                 ]}',
                '$.employees[*]'
                COLUMNS (employee_id NUMBER PATH '$.employee_id', 
                         salary NUMBER PATH '$.salary'));
```

I created a dbFiddle for this: [Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e6114cf0d9db3022976bbc062903fa36)

Comment: That's almost what I need, the difference between this and the insertxml() is that I would need to supply the column names rather than then being taken from the tags in the XML.

Comment: @Jackson - Oracle's JSON implementation is deliberately lightweight, because they got burned with XML. They introduced XML processing in Oracle 8i (by wapping Java classes in PL/SQL skins), gave us the full native implementation including XMLTYPE in 9i and were still fixing problems in 12c a good decade and a half later. They are not going to do the same with JSON, even though a lot of the JSON functionality is just the XML functions repurposed to handle different brackets :-)